# Cannot install Visual Studio from PowerShell script

Tags: windows, powershell, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to install visual studio through PowerShell, works fine on local computer, but I keep getting errors when I run it on our AWS windows server 2012R2. I've attached my code and error below. Thank you

[powershell script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZVU8.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAwJU.png)

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

$here = pwd
$software = "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer";
$installed = (Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where { $_.DisplayName -eq $software }) -ne $null



#If VSCode was not installed before, it will be download required files and install it.

If(-Not $installed)

{

Write-Host "'$software' is NOT installed.";

wget https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_community.exe -outfile “vs.exe”

.\vs.exe install --quiet --norestart

}
#If VSCode was installed before, it will try to update it to the newer version, if available.

#If no updates available, it will do nothing.

else

{

Write-Host "'$software' is installed."

if ( Test-Path -Path $here\vs.exe )

{

.\vs.exe update --quiet --norestart

}

else {

wget https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_community.exe -outfile "vs.exe"

.\vs.exe update --quiet --norestart

}

}
```

Comment: Do not paste screenshots. Instead, copy and paste the error.

Comment: See [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: @adekola: Editing help - https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: If this script works fine on your local computer then the file named `vs.exe` already existed prior to running the script.

Answer (score 1):

You have used the option `-outfile vs.exe` but this is not how you tell `wget` to rename the downloaded file. What this actually does is the following:

1. downloads the file to `vs_community.exe` (because that's the filename in the original URL)
2. writes a log file to `utfile`
3. ignores the `vs.exe` parameter

The wget option to direct the downloaded content to a named file is actually `-O`, not `-outfile` (which is the equivalent of `-o utfile`, which writes the log to `utfile`).

To specify the correct output filename, use:

```
-O vs.exe
```

Or simply execute `wget https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_community.exe` and then execute the downloaded file, which is named `vs_community.exe`.